Region of feasible $(E,V)$ for a discrete random variable supported on ${1,2,\dots,k}$
Given a discrete random variable taking on the first $k$ positive integer values with probability $p_i$, $i=1,\dots,k$, how can I compute the region of feasible combinations $(E,V)$, where $E=\sum_{i=1}^k ip_i$ and $V=\sum_{i=1}^k (i-E)^2p_i$ are the expected value and variance, respectively?
I expect to find a parabolic-bell shaped region, but I don't know how to find the equation of it

It is easy to check that $E$ can take any real value between $1$ and $k$.
For a given $E$, let $V^-$ be the minimal feasible variance and $V^+$ the maximal one.
The maximal one is attained when the whole mass is concentrated on $\{1,k\}$. That means $p_1+p_k=1$ and $p_1+kp_k=E$, that is $p_1=\frac{k-E}{k-1}$ and $p_k=\frac{E-1}{k-1}$. So $V^+=(E-1)(k-E)$.
If $E\in\{1,\cdots,k\}$ then clearly $V^-=0$. Otherwise the minimum variance is attained when the mass is concentrated on $\{e,e+1\}$ where $e$ is the floor part of $E$. That means $p_e+p_{e+1}=1$ and $ep_e+(e+1)p_{e_1}=E$, that is $p_e=e+1-E$ and $p_{e+1}=E-e$. So $V^-=(E-e)(e+1-E)$.
Now let us show that any variance $V\in[V^-,V^+]$ is feasible. Choose probability values $p^-_1,\cdots,p^-_k$ which yield expected value $E$ and variance $V^-$, and probability values $p^+_1,\cdots,p^+_k$ which yield expected value $E$ and variance $V^+$. Now set $p_i=\lambda p^+_i+(1-\lambda)p^-_i$ for some $\lambda\in[0,1]$. Clearly the probability values $p_1,\cdots,p_k$ yield the expected value $E$ and variance $\lambda V^++(1-\lambda)V^-$. As $[V^-,V^+]=\{\lambda V^++(1-\lambda)V^-\mid\lambda\in[0,1]\}$, this proves the claim.
Conclusion: the set of feasible $(E,V)$ is
$$
\{(E,v)\mid E\in[1,k],\ (E-\lfloor E\rfloor)(\lceil E\rceil-1)\le v\le(E-1)(k-E)\}.
$$
For example for $k=6$ that is the area between the red and blue curves in the picture below.


Thank you very much, it's very clear now!
